# Spree Auth Devise Redirection Trying to Access /admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

trying to get familiar with Spree and am following the official tutorial (https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html).

Certainly straightforward enough, but when I try to hit localhost:3000/admin the server returns a 302 to /admin/orders and then a 302 to /login, which fails.

I can confirm that localhost:3000 works fine and the test storefront loads.

Anyone else see something similar? The error is the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end ...ion only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_tim... ... ^ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end ..."devise.skip_timeout"] = true } ... ^
```

This is curious given how straightforward this tutorial is. Has anyone seen something similar?

Interestingly this also happens when I follow the default login route at the top of the default store set up. Login is failing from there as well.

Answer (score 2):

add this line in your Gemfile `gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise'`

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a versioning issue with an open problem for the newest spree + devise combo. I rolled back my ruby version and it worked fine.